# Use docker system prune to filter networks

Tags: docker

I want to use the command `docker system prune` to remove all unused containers and images, but I want network with a certain driver to be kept alive.

If I run `docker system prune --filter "driver!=foo"` I get the following result: `Invalid filter 'driver!'`.

When I use `docker network ls` I can filtering a specific driver using `docker network ls --filter driver=foo`.

How can I filter a certain driver in docker system prune?

Answer (score 1):

The filter you are trying to apply is not supported. As a workaround, you can use `label` when creating the network:

```
$ docker network create --label=mynet your_network_name_here
```

and then use:

```
docker system prune --filter "label!=mynet"
```

The [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) mention that `docker system prune` supports 2 filter cases:

> #### Filtering
>
> The currently supported filters are:
>
> - until (`<timestamp>`) - only remove containers, images, and networks created before given timestamp
> - label (`label=<key>`, `label=<key>=<value>`, `label!=<key>`, or `label!=<key>=<value>`) - only remove containers, images, networks, and volumes with (or without, in case `label!=...` is used) the specified labels.

#### Example:

```
$ docker network create test-1
13ce668830472bb33d2d2b4be5b3236b59df4ea5d20f571e5ba04359ea3617f1

$ docker network create test-2
46a4bb3021250667fd26bf8d76bd06f789c7cf8149ab698b1cec40e1c23d34ad

$ docker network create test-3
a4c2f507e767dfef12684ce451e855a88225c44fcadfdbed7c7cd4502fd0cdd2

$ docker network create --label=mynet test-4
41e9d3c38c1de54e6bb4e25784d73ef7bfbe3e848208a130eb2564c46670a330

$ docker system prune --filter "label!=mynet"
WARNING! This will remove:
        - all stopped containers
        - all networks not used by at least one container
        - all dangling images
        - all dangling build cache
        - Elements to be pruned will be filtered with:
        - label={"label!":{"mynet":true}}
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted Networks:
test-1
test-2
test-3

Total reclaimed space: 0B

$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
3ca2cec4eda2        bridge              bridge              local
dc9d8ffaed44        host                host                local
d21298cd02e3        none                null                local
41e9d3c38c1d        test-4              bridge              local
```